# set wallpaper from assets image in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I'm creating a flutter app with wallpaper capability. and to achieve this I'm using [flutter_wallpaper_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wallpaper_manager) package with [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager). but the cache manager doesn't use the assets directly `assets/images/image.jpg`. or I'm missing something?

```
onTap: () async {
  int location = WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN;
  var path = await DefaultCacheManager()
      .getSingleFile(widget.img.toString());
  bool result = await WallpaperManager
      .setWallpaperFromFile(
          path.path, location);
},
```

the cache manager fetches from URL, not assets. how can I make wallpaper functionality work?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to find a solution and I settled on this option.

```
enter code here
Future<void> setWallpaper() async {
    try {
      final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/5.jpg');
      final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/5.jpg');
      await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

      int location = WallpaperManager
          .BOTH_SCREEN; // or location = WallpaperManager.LOCK_SCREEN;

      final bool result =
      await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(file.path, location);
      print(result);
    } on PlatformException {}
  }
```